# ps display thread name

Tags: linux, pthreads, ps

Is there a way for `ps` (or similar tool) to display the pthread's name?
I wrote the following simple program:

```
// th_name.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void * f1() {
    printf("f1 : Starting sleep\n");
    sleep(30);
    printf("f1 : Done sleep\n");
}

int main() {

    pthread_t  f1_thread;
    pthread_create(&f1_thread, NULL, f1, NULL);
    pthread_setname_np(f1_thread, "f1_thread");

    printf("Main : Starting sleep\n");
    sleep(40);
    printf("Main : Done sleep\n");
    return 0;

}
```

Is there a command/utility (like `ps`) that I can use to display the threads for the above program, along with their name.

```
$ /tmp/th_name > /dev/null &
[3] 2055
$ ps -eLf | egrep "th_name|UID"
UID        PID  PPID   LWP  C NLWP STIME TTY          TIME CMD
aal      31088 29342 31088  0    2 10:01 pts/4    00:00:00 /tmp/th_name
aal      31088 29342 31089  0    2 10:01 pts/4    00:00:00 /tmp/th_name
aal      31095 29342 31095  0    1 10:01 pts/4    00:00:00 egrep th_name|UID
```

I am running my program on Ubuntu 12.10.

Answer (score 21):

With procps-ng (https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps) there are output option `-L` and `-T` which will print threads names:

```
$ ps -eL
$ ps -eT
```

`-l` long format may be used with them:

```
$ ps -eLl
$ ps -eTl
```

but `-f` option will replace thread name with full command line which is the same for all threads.

Answer (score 14):

note the [man page of pthread_setname_np()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_setname_np),which have showed how to get the threads' names:

> pthread_setname_np() internally writes to the thread specific comm
>   file under /proc filesystem: /proc/self/task/[tid]/comm.
>   pthread_getname_np() retrieves it from the same location.

and

> Example
>
> The program below demonstrates the use of pthread_setname_np() and
>   pthread_getname_np().
>
> The following shell session shows a sample run of the program:
>
> $ ./a.out
>
> Created a thread. Default name is: a.out
>
> The thread name after setting it is THREADFOO.
>
> **^Z**    #Suspend the program
>
> [1](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_setname_np)+  Stopped           ./a.out
>
> **$ ps H -C a.out -o 'pid tid cmd comm'**
>
> PID   TID     CMD   COMMAND
>
> 5990      5990 ./a.out    a.out
>
> 5990  5991 ./a.out THREADFOO
>
> **$ cat /proc/5990/task/5990/comm**
>
> a.out
>
> **$ cat /proc/5990/task/5991/comm**
>
> THREADFOO

Answer (score 13):

Show the thread IDs and names of the process with PID 12345:

```
ps H -o 'tid comm' 12345
```