# Perl threads- can they be named uniquely? (Linux)

Tags: linux, multithreading, perl

in reference to this from [perlvar](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html):

> *In multithreaded scripts Perl coordinates the threads so that any thread may modify its copy of the $0 and the change becomes visible to ps(1) (assuming the operating system plays along). Note that the view of $0 the other threads have will not change since they have their own copies of it.*

I don't seem to be getting this behavior. Instead, the $0 seems to be shared by all my threads, and in the ps output, the top level main perl interpreter's cmdline is being modified to the final value applied by the last thread.

eg. 
My goal is instead of having this where all threads a named the same under COMMAND column:

```
top -b -n 1 -H -p 223860

top - 17:54:56 up 73 days,  2:15,  7 users,  load average: 0.23, 0.70, 0.92
Threads:  22 total,   0 running,  22 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  0.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni,100.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem : 32358832 total, 26418060 free,  1090028 used,  4850744 buff/cache
KiB Swap: 16777212 total, 16149116 free,   628096 used. 30804716 avail Mem

   PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
223860 app_sy+  20   0 3833640 166216   2500 S  0.0  0.5   0:45.75 tool_reader.
223863 app_sy+  20   0 3833640 166216   2500 S  0.0  0.5   0:03.88 tool_reader.
223864 app_sy+  20   0 3833640 166216   2500 S  0.0  0.5   0:04.67 tool_reader.
223865 app_sy+  20   0 3833640 166216   2500 S  0.0  0.5   0:00.00 tool_reader.
223867 app_sy+  20   0 3833640 166216   2500 S  0.0  0.5   0:34.62 tool_reader.
223868 app_sy+  20   0 3833640 166216   2500 S  0.0  0.5   0:03.85 tool_reader.
223869 app_sy+  20   0 3833640 166216   2500 S  0.0  0.5   0:04.41 tool_reader.
223870 app_sy+  20   0 3833640 166216   2500 S  0.0  0.5   0:00.00 tool_reader.
223872 app_sy+  20   0 3833640 166216   2500 S  0.0  0.5   0:40.14 tool_reader.
```

To have something more useful under the command column like this, and the main thread stays the same.

```
                                                                             |
                                                                             |
                                                                             |
                                                                             v
top -b -n 1 -H -p 223860

top - 17:54:56 up 73 days,  2:15,  7 users,  load average: 0.23, 0.70, 0.92
Threads:  22 total,   0 running,  22 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  0.0 us,  0.0 sy,  0.0 ni,100.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem : 32358832 total, 26418060 free,  1090028 used,  4850744 buff/cache
KiB Swap: 16777212 total, 16149116 free,   628096 used. 30804716 avail Mem

   PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
223860 app_sy+  20   0 3833640 166216   2500 S  0.0  0.5   0:45.75 tool_reader.
223863 app_sy+  20   0 3833640 166216   2500 S  0.0  0.5   0:03.88 syncer
223864 app_sy+  20   0 3833640 166216   2500 S  0.0  0.5   0:04.67 partition1
223865 app_sy+  20   0 3833640 166216   2500 S  0.0  0.5   0:00.00 partition2
223867 app_sy+  20   0 3833640 166216   2500 S  0.0  0.5   0:34.62 partition3
223868 app_sy+  20   0 3833640 166216   2500 S  0.0  0.5   0:03.85 input_merger1
223869 app_sy+  20   0 3833640 166216   2500 S  0.0  0.5   0:04.41 input_merger2
223870 app_sy+  20   0 3833640 166216   2500 S  0.0  0.5   0:00.00 input_merger3
```

Would anyone know how this can be done? I'm using a rather old perl now, version 5.16.3, in case this was a bug?

Comment: Re "*I don't seem to be getting this behavior*", [I do](https://pastebin.com/aaLEtq9B). Changing `$0` in one thread has no effect on `$0` in other threads, just like the docs say. That said, changing `$0` in one thread does change the command showed by `ps` for all threads of the process, but the docs didn't say otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for your reply- I poorly worded my question.  I meant that Linux's view is changing, $0 inside each thread does change and is isolated from each other correctly.  From your example, the output under the CMD column changes from 3 "thr1" then to 3 "thr2".  What i was hoping to be possible was have the main Perl CMD string set to the name of the script that was called + any args, and the 2nd thread = "thr1", and the 3rd set to "thr2" .   Is that possible?

Comment: I've never heard of threads having their own command, but I don't really know.

Comment: [It is possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17514771/ps-display-thread-name) using [`pthread_setname_np`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_setname_np.3.html). You could work towards having support for it added to threads.pm, or you could call it [FFI::Platypus](https://metacpan.org/pod/FFI::Platypus)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update 2020-10-21:**
I just discovered an even better way to achieve this - the actual linux syscall. https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/prctl.2.html

Troels Liebe Bentsen has kindly contributed a module that handles this neatly.
https://metacpan.org/pod/Sys::Prctl

Far more seamless than fiddling with $0 !!!

*Original Post content continues below....*

```
ps -T -p 126193
   PID   SPID TTY          TIME CMD
126193 126193 pts/11   00:00:00 test2.pl
126193 126194 pts/11   00:00:00 __thr1      #<--- now unique
126193 126195 pts/11   00:00:00 __thr2      #<--- now unique
```

```
top -H -p 126193

   PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
126193 xxxxxxx+  20   0  305948   7972   2244 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.01 test2.pl
126194 xxxxxxx+  20   0  305948   7972   2244 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 __thr1
126195 xxxxxxx+  20   0  305948   7972   2244 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 __thr2
```

##################

Thanks to @ikegami , I found a solution that will work.

Couple of small changes were needed in order to get keep the child threads alive, and also needed to stop the main thread from joining them back in. (Based on how it behaves, I assume that if the child threads reach the end of the sub they are spawned with, they are completely terminated and Linux cleans them up - even though the main thread hasn't called `join` on them yet.

To anyone else reading this page in future, I would love to know why each of pstree, ps, and top, all show a different result.

Any how, leaving this info and comparisons here in case its helpful to others.

**End result:**

- Using `ps` command , it does NOT appear to be possible to get the modified name of the threads. It only shows the string of what the last thread that touched $0 set it to
- Similarly, using pstree `pstree -p -a -l 144741` also only shows the main thread as the name for each child, and does not show anything about the changes made by the threads
- But, very fortunately, using top works!!!! `top -H -b -p 180547` , which clearly shows the main thread, and all child threads by the name they set using $0

Example from ps:

```
app_sy+ 180547 131203 180547  0    3 18:08 pts/1    00:00:00 thr2
app_sy+ 180547 131203 180548  0    3 18:08 pts/1    00:00:00 thr2
app_sy+ 180547 131203 180549  0    3 18:08 pts/1    00:00:00 thr2
```

Example using pstree:

```
test.pl,180547
  |-{test.pl},180548
  `-{test.pl},180549
```

And the winner, using `top -n 1 -H -b -p 180547` , which shows the distinct names applied to $0 by each thread successfully!!!!!!

```
top - 18:00:08 up 69 days,  8:53,  3 users,  load average: 4.10, 3.95, 4.05
Threads:   3 total,   0 running,   3 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  7.7 us, 33.5 sy,  0.0 ni, 58.8 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem : 13144056+total,  1351640 free, 45880316 used, 84208608 buff/cache
KiB Swap: 16777212 total, 16777212 free,        0 used. 78196224 avail Mem

   PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
180547 app_+     20   0  299572   7152   2144 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 test.pl
180548 app_+     20   0  299572   7152   2144 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.02 thr1
180549 app_+     20   0  299572   7152   2144 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.01 thr2
```

Adding Modified version of Ikegami's code here for future reference for others looking at this page, saved as test.pl :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw( say );
use threads;
use threads::shared;

my $phase :shared = 0;
my $main_pid = $$;
sub advance {
   lock $phase;
   ++$phase;
   cond_signal($phase);
}

sub wait_for {
   lock $phase;
   cond_wait($phase) while $phase != $_[0];
}

sub advance_and_wait_for {
   lock $phase;
   ++$phase;
   cond_signal($phase);
   cond_wait($phase) while $phase != $_[0];
}

my $thr1 = async {
   my $id = 'thr1';
   wait_for(0);
   advance_and_wait_for(2);
   say "[$id] Setting \$0 to $id.";
   $0 = $id;
   say "[$id] \$0 = $0";
   print `ps -eLf|grep $main_pid` =~ s/^/[$id] /mrg;
   advance_and_wait_for(4);
   say "[$id] \$0 = $0";
   advance();
    while(1){
        sleep 1;
    }
};

my $thr2 = async {
   my $id = 'thr2';
   wait_for(1);
   advance_and_wait_for(3);
   say "[$id] \$0 = $0";
   say "[$id] Setting \$0 to $id.";
   $0 = $id;
   say "[$id] \$0 = $0";
   print `ps -eLf| grep $main_pid` =~ s/^/[$id] /mrg;
   advance();
    while(1){
        sleep 1;
    }

};
sleep 5;
print "Main thread pid is $main_pid - and \$0 is ($0)\n";

my $waitfor = <STDIN>;

$_->join for $thr1, $thr2;
```